# Why does the whole Layer fill in when i try to fill in a section on Gimp?

Tags: gimp, texture

I'm trying to do this texture for imvu but everytime I try to fill in this one section it fills in the whole layer can you please help me?

(this is before i pressed cntrl ,)

[image]

this is after I pressed Cntrl ,[image]

(this is after I pressed Cntrl ,)

I just want to know why it keeps doing this. The first time i did it, it worked out well but now it keeps on doing this I just want to know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. "Fill" is a paint operation and you are only showing paths. If you want to "fill" the inside of path, get a Selection from the path (Select>From path) and then bucket-fill the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @xenoid's comment:

#### What a path is

What you see in your second screenshot, shown as circles joined by lines, is a path. Paths can be used for a lot of things, like creating reusable shapes, etc. They define a set lines that can be traced, aligned (to), exported to a vector graphic (like .svg) and used to create selections.

#### What a selection is

A selection is a part of a layer that can be modified. This is shown as a moving black and white outline. The easiest way to see this is the *Rectangle Select Tool* (upper leftmost in your toolbox).

#### How to use this for your problem

In order to fill your desired area, create a selection from the path. This can be done, for example when using the Paths dialog. Click on `Windows -> Dockable Dialogs -> Paths`. This should give you a list of paths. Most certainly there will be only one in the list. If you are not sure that you got the right one, try toggling the visibility of the path(s) using the two checkboxes left of the path names. This works just like with layers. Right click on it and choose `Path to Selection`.

Then you will have a selection that you can fill.